# Different sample delays using xcorr and finddelay in Matlab

Tags: matlab, timedelay

I am trying to find the time delay between two ultrasound pulses using Matlab, I have tried using xcorr and finddelay (which uses xcorr) but I get two different results. I would like to know why this is, and which I can consider to be the correct result. Ideally I would like to get xcorr working correctly as it would be useful to plot the cross-correlation.

Example data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kNu4B40PiL1hvX4dOk-clg8CT6wZGerf).

```
myfile = uigetfile('*.csv','MultiSelect','on');
M = readtable(myfile);
A = table2array(M);
A(1,:) = [];

Time = A(:,1);
Input = A(:,2);
Output = A(:,3);

Fs = 500e6;

d1 = finddelay(Input,Output) / Fs;
[c,lags]=xcorr(Input,Output);
d2 = -(lags(c == max(c))) / Fs;
```

Edit: Thanks to Mansour Torabi I have extracted the `xcorr` code from `finddelay` to find the normalised cross correlation:

```
x = Input;
y = Output;
maxlag = 50000;

% FINDDELAY for column vectors x and y.
% The inputs cxx0 and cyy0 should be:
cxx0 = sum(abs(x).^2);
cyy0 = sum(abs(y).^2);
% Initialize some constants.
ZERO = coder.internal.indexInt(0);
ONE = coder.internal.indexInt(1);
nc = 2*maxlag + 1;
d = ZERO;
max_c = coder.internal.scalarEg(x,y);
scale = sqrt(cxx0*cyy0);
% Quick return for trivial inputs. Empty inputs will have scale == 0.
if maxlag == 0 || scale == 0
    return
end
index_max = ZERO;
index_max_pos = ONE;
index_max_neg = ONE;
[c,lag] = xcorr(x,y,maxlag);
% Process the negative lags in flipped order.
max_c_neg = abs(c(maxlag))/scale;
for k = 2:maxlag
    vneg = abs(c(maxlag - k + 1))/scale;
    if vneg > max_c_neg
        max_c_neg = vneg;
        index_max_neg = k;
    end
end
% Process the positive lags.
max_c_pos = abs(c(maxlag + 1))/scale;
for k = maxlag + 2:nc
    vpos = abs(c(k))/scale;
    if vpos > max_c_pos
        max_c_pos = vpos;
        index_max_pos = k - maxlag;
    end
end
if maxlag == 0
    % Case where MAXLAG is zero.
    index_max = index_max_pos;
elseif max_c_pos > max_c_neg
    % The estimated lag is positive or zero.
    index_max = maxlag + index_max_pos;
    max_c = max_c_pos;
elseif max_c_pos < max_c_neg
    % The estimated lag is negative.
    index_max = maxlag + 1 - index_max_neg;
    max_c = max_c_neg;
elseif max_c_pos == max_c_neg
    max_c = max_c_pos;
    if index_max_pos <= index_max_neg
        % The estimated lag is positive or zero.
        index_max = maxlag + index_max_pos;
    else
        % The estimated lag is negative.
        index_max = maxlag + 1 - index_max_neg;
    end
end
%delay in samples
d = (maxlag + 1) - index_max;
%delay in time
dfcc = d/Fs;

%convert from samples to time and take abs value (scale 0-1)
xcorrlag = abs(lag/Fs);
c = abs(c/max(abs(c)));
```

This can then be plotted using:

```
plot(xcorrlag,c,[dfcc dfcc],[-1 1],'r:')  
text(dfcc+0.00001,0.5,['ToF: ' num2str(dfcc) ' s'])
```

The maximum correlation is highlighted and labelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB `finddelay` function is a m-file, so you can see the codes inside it.
If so, you will find that the `finddely`function do the **Normalized Cross-Correlation** instead of **Cross-Correlation**. This is the reason that results of `xcorr` and `finddelay` are slightly different.

And I should note that for delay detection, **Normalized Cross-Correlation (NCC)** is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. xcorr has an input argument for controlling normalization (scaleopt) but setting this to 'normalized' (or any of the options) does not affect the result. Looking at finddelay I can see: scale = sqrt(cxx0*cyy0); which I assume is the normalization step, is this correct?

Comment: According to MATLAB Help, the input argument in the xcorr, is just a constant scaling, but the normalization in finddelay is different, the code line: abs(xcorr(x(:,i),y(:,i),maxlag(i)))/sqrt(cxx0(i)*cyy0(i))
calculates normalized cross-correlation